# How do I comment on Mark Zuckerberg's posts?

Tags: facebook, comments

I want to know how to comment on Mark Zuckerberg's posts. When I see his posts the comments are either from people in his personal relation or they are employees at Facebook.

However, there are some comments by people who have no connection with him but can still comment on his post. I asked one of them by message but I haven't had any reply.

I want to know how they comment if they aren't friends with him.

Comment: Show me the money: http://www.forbes.com/sites/kashmirhill/2013/01/11/would-you-pay-100-to-send-mark-zuckerberg-a-facebook-message/

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra i want to comment on posts, not message. do you know how do they comment?

Answer (score 4):

Public posts allow anyone to comment on them *unless* you have `Followers` enabled with the correct settings. With the correct settings, only `Friends` or `Friends of Friends` may comment on even public posts.

Mark Zuckerberg probably has `Followers` turned on with the `Friends of Friends` setting enabled for commenting access. The people you see commenting don't have to be directly connected to him.

To [do this yourself](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/216792731707396?rdrhc), you can

1. Click the gear icon in the top right
2. Click `Followers` in the left-hand menu
3. Click `Turn On Follow` if it is not already enabled
4. Change the `Follower Comments` setting away from `Everybody`